# How to approach IFrame and LoadableComponent in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

what would be a good approach in modelling a page using LoadableComponent when most of the content is in an iframe? I was thinking about an inner class, but not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dealt with IFrames much, but I believe that LoadableComponent would still be a good way to do it.  I do have many pages that contain other pages referenced within itself.

However, I cannot think of a way to have the pages do a seamless switch to the iframe and back (unless you want to write a custom getter for each element), so that would still need to be in your test code.

Comment: What I do at the moment is have a class variable which is true or false depending if the frame is selected or not, so any method knows if the frame is selected. Still, I feel that a more elegant approach is possible..

Comment: If you had two inner classes, one for in the IFrame, one that's out, and the outer class simply remembered which frame you were in, and both of the classes were private, and in their getters, you could initiate a switchTo() in their getters.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
driver.switchTo().frame("marco");
```

replace "marco" with your own frame name

Comment: Yeah, that's how I switch to a frame, but still, this does not cover the page modelling approach..